# Got an "Oops" Screen While in Installer, Exited to Try Again, and Now I Can't Get Back to Installer

Tags: installation

Background info: trying to install Craft CMS on a Vm running on Xubuntu

So, I was *finally* able to see the glorious monkey screen to signify that I'd made it to the installer successfully, when disaster struck soon afterward... I began the installation, enter my info, and ended up waiting on a very, very long "Oops" screen that just seemed to keep going and going. I looked up some resources about the install process while I waited and thought I'd done something wrong, so I exited the window to try again, because no "back" option was available. When I went to the URL again to reenter my info, I got a screen saying "Page Not Found: The requested URL was not found on this server." I did absolutely nothing after exiting the installer, checked to see that the file I was using in the URL is still where it should be, and restarting Apache (and then my VM) didn't help either, so now I'm stuck.

What should I do? Any and all advice will be very greatly appreciated. I can't find the answer anywhere I've looked!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I feel silly posting an answer to my own question, but I wanted to post the solution in case anyone else ran across this, instead of just deleting the question.

I was using the URL http: //localhost/public/index.php/admin/install to get to the installer, and I think it wouldn't let me go back because the installation-- somehow-- was actually successful. I started playing around with the URL and found that http: //localhost/public/index.php/admin brought me to the admin dashboard. Trying to put in the address I gave the site is still throwing a Page Not Found at me, but I'm hoping that's because everything is there but not quite wired-up correctly yet; I'll try to come back and edit this if I find that there is more that should be included here to remedy this.

Comment: I've seen that before, though I never figured out why. Seems like if you make it as far as the "Oops" screen, then it actually worked.

Comment: Everything _seems_ to be in order as of now, but I'm still feeling a little leery lol

Comment: A tiny tip if you'd pull everything from the public folder into your main folder and set your .htaccess right you don't neet to put public/index.php/ in your url :)

Comment: Don't feel silly @scoffin, you're doing it right! Now accept that answer and give yourself a high five.